# Don't Email Distribution Group Owner

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2013

In our Exchange 2013 system when a new distributionn group is created it is requiring us to give it an owner. When you add a owner they then also recieve emails sent to this group (the check to add them as a group member is clear). Is it possible to set things up where the owner doesn't get emails but can still manage groups? Or even a way to create a distribution group in Exchange 2013 without giving it an owner?

Thanks

Comment: You won't run into this issue if you add groups via Powershell.

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks, that is something to keep in mind. Appears to be a shortcoming in the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, which wasn't obvious to me since I was only using the Exchange Admin Center tool.

After creating the group in the above mentioned tool I tehn went into Active Directory Users and Groups and looked at the group. The person I had added as the owner in the Exchnage too (but not as a member) was listed as a member here. I removed them from the Member list but kept them as the owner. Now emails to this group do not go to the group owner.